# How can I obtain server variables using apache wicket 1.54?

Tags: java, apache, web-applications, wicket

I am trying to get the name and ip of the current server in which my web application is running on. I am not sure how to do this is wicket 1.54. I need to know how to get at my server variables.

In wicket 1.4 you could do:

```
HttpServletRequest hsr = getWebRequestCycle().getWebRequest().getHttpServletRequest();
```

Then you could use hsr to grab headers or attributes.

Edit:

In wicket 1.54 the equivalent line is:

```
HttpServletRequest hsr = (HttpServletRequest)getRequestCycle().getRequest().getContainerRequest();
hsr.getAttribute("SERVER_NAME");
```

However I always am getting a null string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me with Wicket 1.5.5 inside a WebPage:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) getRequest().getContainerRequest();
String serverName = request.getServerName();
String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Comment: Indeed. You need to use #getServerName() method, not #getAttribute()